# Convert getFullYear method to an Integer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some trouble to substract from the methode getFullYear(). The function's return is NaN.
I don't find how I could convert the value of getFullYear() to an Integer.

```
process.stdin.resume()
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8')

console.log('How old are you?')
process.stdin.on('data', (number) => {

  if (isNaN(number)){
    console.log("the value should be a number");
  }
  else if (number>99){
    console.log("the value can't be ahead 99");
  }
  else{
    let actualYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    console.log("You were born in " + Number(actualYear)- number);
  }

  process.exit();
})
```

Comment: Add `number = Number(number);` as the first line of your function. You also do NOT need the `Number(actualYear)` below. Just plain `actualYear` is fine -- it will already be a number. The thing that is not the number is your user input.

Comment: No, it's a `string` containing numeric-looking values. Test it with `console.log(typeof number);`.

Comment: That's mean at the moment where I put the methode in a variable, I can play with it as a number??

Answer (score 4):

take paranthesis your math function

```
console.log("You were born in " + (actualYear- number));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're appending a string `"You were born in "` to your `Number(actualYear)` which makes it a string. Hence you get `NaN` upon subtracting `number` from it.
Try doing this:

```
Console.log("You were born in " + (Number(actualYear)- number))
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, you are very close. you have to do `(curYear - num)`

```js
process.stdin.resume()
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8')

console.log('How old are you?')
process.stdin.on('data', (number) => {
  if (isNaN(number)){
    console.log("the value should be a number");
  } else {
    const num = parseInt(number, 10);
    if (number > 99) {
      console.log("the value can't be ahead 99");
    } else {
      const curYear = new Date().getFullYear();
      console.log("You were born in " + (curYear - num));
    }
  }
  process.exit();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `number` to an `integer`:

```js
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("utf8");

console.log("How old are you?");

process.stdin.on("data", (number) => {
  // convert `number` to an `integer`, then do the comparison
  const age = parseInt(number, 10);

  // this will still be applicable as all invalid
  // arguments to `parseInt` will result in a `NaN`
  if (isNaN(age)) {
    console.log("the value should be a number");
  } else if (age > 99) {
    console.log("the value can't be ahead 99");
  } else {
    const currYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    const yearBorn = currYear - age;

    console.log("You were born in", yearBorn);
  }
  process.exit();
})
```